# Redirect STDERR to a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, stdout, stderr

I have this code that produces an error, and it works to supress the STDOUT but it doesnt store the STDERR in the variable ERROR.

```
ERROR = $(memtester 900 1 > /dev/null)
```

Comment: you can't have spaces around `=` in a shell variable assignment.

Comment: And you shouldn't use uppercase variable names, those are reserved for application environment variables.

Comment: Redirect stderr to stdout is done by 2>&1, & is used to follow a file descriptor. So the following code should work for you. `ERROR=$({ memtester 900 > /dev/null; } 2>&1`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can capture it like this:

```
error=$(memtester 900 1 2>&1 >/dev/null)
```

order of redirection operators is important here.

- `2>&1` - redirects stderr to stdout
- `>/dev/null` - redirects stdout to `/dev/null`

Comment: why do we need the redirection to /dev/null? Won't that lose the output?

Comment: @djna Normal output will be lost indeed, but obviously by OP the point is to capture only the command error (if any). Without `>/dev/null` this variable will contain also the ouput.

Comment: @user2489314: Did this work for you?

Comment: @George Vasilou but stderr has been redirected to stdout, so stderr output is sent to /dev/null too. As this stands the error variable will contain nothing.

Comment: @djna - No , This is not how redirection works. The command `2>&1' does not mean follow the &1 (stdout). Means send the fd 2 (stderr) to wherever fd1 CURRENTLY goes = command (pipe) buffer or /dev/tty if run directly from CLI. If you later redirect fd1 to somewhere else (a file or like in this answer to dev/null), fd2 still goes to the device which fd1 was bound before (command pipe or /dev/tty in command line). It is very well explained here : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002

Comment: @George Vasilou Aha! Thanks George. (There was a time when I knew this stuff ;-)